# Share.js not working with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, share.js

Server Side code,

```
var express = require('express'); //Web Framework
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app); //HTTP server module
var connect = require('connect'),
    sharejs = require('share').server;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


var options = {db: {type: 'none'}}; // See docs for options. {type: 'redis'} to enable persistance.

// Attach the sharejs REST and Socket.io interfaces to the server
sharejs.attach(server, options);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
})


http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

But I cant get the share.js to work.

It gives an error, ReferenceError: server is not defined

How do I get express to work along with share.js?

Comment: did you install it, `npm install share`? also I think you should instantiate it this way: `require('share').server;`

Comment: Tried it, no result!

Comment: you got any other error, or the same one?

Comment: TypeError:  Object #<Server> has no method 'use', this one

Comment: you should pass a `server` object as the first argument instead of `http` in `sharejs.attach(http, options);`. please see the [documentation](https://github.com/share/ShareJS/wiki/Getting-started-%280.6.x%29#running-a-server)

Comment: Check the updated question and the answer!

Answer (score 0):

### ShareJS 0.6

If you're using ShareJS 0.6, the issue is that you're using `require('share').http` instead of `require('share').server`.

Change:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    sharejs = require('share').http;
```

To:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    sharejs = require('share').server;
```

### ShareJS 0.7

If you're using ShareJS 0.7, the `attach` method has been deprecated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20313251/1317805) for a workaround.

---

### Update

Now that your answer has been updated, the problem is that you haven't defined the `server` variable. [The documentation](https://github.com/share/ShareJS/wiki/Getting-started-%280.6.x%29) states that you can define this using:

> ```
> var server = connect(
>       connect.logger(),
>       connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
>     );
> ```

Comment: Changed it to server. Using 0.6.3, not working, give this error, TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'use'

Comment: No, still doesn't work. 
TypeError: Object function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  merge(app, proto);
  merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  return app;
} has no method 'logger'
Express with share really seems to be like an issue

Comment: @KevinDesai in that case I don't think I'm able to help further. Might be worth raising this as an issue on ShareJS's GitHub repository: https://github.com/share/ShareJS.